# How can I create a virtual environment with virtualenv for Python 3.7 without having to install Python 3.7 on my computer (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS x64)?

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

How can I create a virtual environment with `virtualenv` for Python 3.7 without having to install Python 3.7 on my computer (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS x64)?

```
virtualenv -p python3.7 /mnt/ilcompn0d1/user/dernonco/pyenv/codetest
```

yields:

```
The executable python3.7 (from --python=python3.7) does not exist
```

but I would prefer not to have to install Python 3.7 on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install Python 3.7 system-wide, but you do need to install it *somewhere* if you want to use it in a virtualenv. Easy options include via [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) or [`pythonz`](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz).

If you install `pyenv`, install Python 3.7 via `pyenv install 3.7`, then create your virtualenv. Or use a higher-level tool like [`Pipenv`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which can manage virtualenvs for you and install them via `pyenv` automatically:

1. Install `pyenv`
2. Install `pipenv`, e.g. with `pip install --user pipenv`
3. In a project directory, create  new virtualenv using `pipenv`:

   ```
   pipenv install --python 3.7
   ```

   Python 3.7 will automatically be installed for your user via `pyenv`.

Alternatively, [`pew`](https://pypi.org/project/pew/) can do much the same thing via `pythonz`:

1. Install `pew` with the optional `pythonz` integration:

   ```
   pip install --user pew[pythonz]
   ```
2. Create a new virtualenv:

   ```
   pew new -p $(pythonz locate 3.7) some-name
   ```

Both of these solutions assume that you have the Python user directory added to your `$PATH`. On my system that's `~/.local/bin/`. Use `import site; print(site.USER_BASE)` to double-check on your machine.